# How can transparency be implemented in a Minecraft-like game without sorting the vertices?

Tags: opengl, rendering, raycasting, transparency, raytracing

I'm working on a minecraft clone with OpenGL and I've been trying to implement the rendering of textures with transparency for several days now with out succes.
What techniques can be used to achieve something like 'correct' transparency like in minecraft, without sorting all the vertices?
I aleady tried OIT, but realized that it won't work well in this case.

I'm still new to OpenGL and computer graphics as well... Might Raytraycing or raycasting be an option in this case?

Comment: Minecraft sorts and performs decently on even relatively low-spec hardware. What leads you to believe that you'd need to use a solution more exotic than theirs? Keep in mind that sorting transparent polygons in a voxel grid is much less taxing than sorting every vertex in the whole world, and [you can use the grid structure to help accelerate the work substantially](https://iquilezles.org/www/articles/volumesort/volumesort.htm).

Comment: My Problem is that using my current Structure the sorting would probably be quite hard to implement efficiently. Everytime the player moves I would need to recalcualte the chunkmesh, because my Vertex/Indexbuffer only stores the visibele faces and it would be hard to sort them afterwards.

Comment: When a structure isn't serving your needs, you change the structure.